# WooCommerce Cart not updating

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

If you go to here and add any product to the car, then if you go to the shopping cart and try to adjust the number of items the cart doesn't update. When you hit the UPDATE button it reloads the page and rests the total number of the product back to how it was

[WooCommerce Shop Cart](http://spencerdavieson.com/shop/)

Has anyone come across this behaviour before?

Comment: Don't just link to your site.  This question has zero value to future visitors once your site is fixed or your link changes, goes down, updates, etc.

Comment: @cale_b I'd be happy to paste the code before and after its fixed once I know where the issue is. That way users can see the change that fixed it. But I think its useful to have the live website to troubleshoot the issue to start with